# i made a dynamic list inside a list and i inserted an image how can i call it

Tags: flutter, dart

This my code and I can call the name and the nick by

```dart
 title: Text("${recipe[i]['name']}"),
 subtitle: Text("${recipe[i]['nick']}"),
```

So how I can call the image

```dart
List recipe = [
  {
    "name" : "bruce wayne",
    "nick" : "batman",
    "image" : Image.asset('lib/icons/pizza.png'),

  },
  {
    "name" : "clark kent",
    "nick" : "superman",
    "image" : Image.asset('lib/icons/sushi.jpg'),

  },
  {
    "name" : "peter parker",
    "nick" : "spiderman",
    "image" : Image.asset('lib/icons/kiwi.png'),

  },
  {
    "name" : "bruce banner",
    "nick" : "hulk",
    "image" : Image.asset('lib/icons/macNcheese.png'),

  },
];
```

I tried

```dart
leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: AssetImage('lib/icons/takis.png'),
```

but it only gives me one photo and I am expecting to have a loop of images.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the image by: `recipe[i]['image']`, a widget on its own already and can stand alone. However, to use in a circle avatar, follow the below:

```
CircleAvatar(child: recipe[i]['image']),
```

You should be able to customize the CircleAvatar to suit your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make changes to the list.
You should use string instead of image.asset in the image field.

for example:

```
List recipe = [ { "name" : "bruce wayne", "nick" : "batman", "image" :'lib/icons/pizza.png'}];
        
        ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: recipe.length,
                    itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(recipe[index]['name']),
                        subtitle: Text(recipe[index]['nick']),
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: AssetImage(recipe[index]['image']),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
```